# Is this possible to get knock out unminified source to debug like as angular js?

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js, binding, knockout-mapping-plugin

In angular js, we can get the unminified version in below link

https://code.angularjs.org/0.10.0/

Like this if this is possible to get knock out js code for debugging purpose.

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: what do u need a unminified version of angular or knockout js ?.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.4.0.debug.js from http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/index.html ?

Comment: i need knockout.js

Comment: but this wont work i have already checked. Is this need a any additional / different code?

Comment: given links works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all unminified code from this [link](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/), the "debug" version.

Remember that, if you are in hurry, you can format your minified source code by using this button in chrome developers tools (but that won't fix the name of variables, which will be *still* minified):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Knockout is an Opensource project. You can get sources from Git at https://github.com/knockout/knockout

Get the source and follow "Building Knockout from source" steps. Perhaps you need to modify Grunt config files to disable minified process.